# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 21927 bytes)

Tags: php

I have a big problem with this because I cannot understand the logic on it. I am running php under ubuntu and I am trying to run it via `php -q "script.php"`

The error is on

> return $doc->saveXML();

In php.ini the value is 512M (I've try 128M,-1, 536870912, 64M)

The script is telling me that "Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes"...but from where is this value?

Here is my php file configuration

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

System => Linux HEL-ALFALINk 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:23:46 UTC 2014 i686
Build Date => Oct 29 2014 11:57:49
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-odbc.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_odbc.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini

PHP API => 20121113
PHP Extension => 20121212
Zend Extension => 220121212
Zend Extension Build => API220121212,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20121212,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => enabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
exit_on_timeout => Off => Off
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs => /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear => .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 30 => 30
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 512M => 512M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 128M => 128M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 16K => 16K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 128M => 128M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => Europe/Berlin

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

dba

DBA support => enabled
Supported handlers => cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
dba.default_handler => flatfile => flatfile

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.9.1
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

ereg

Regex Library => Bundled library enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 1.4 $Id$
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
version => 1.0.5-dev

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Id: 4d3899e089e6e45b157975ceef2ac7deb6e9d762 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled

gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.1.1-dev
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.5.2
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 8
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.50
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30411
XBM Support => enabled
WebP Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.19

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.3.2
JSON-C version (bundled) => 0.11

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version => 20901
libXML streams => enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
libmbfl version => 1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check => On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 5.9.2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

mcrypt

mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
Version => 2.5.8
Api No => 20021217
Supported ciphers => cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes 
Supported modes => cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value

mhash

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => 5.5.41
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE => external
MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.connect_timeout => 120 => 120
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off

mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => 5.5.41
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API header version => 5.5.40
MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off

odbc

ODBC Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
ODBC library => unixODBC
ODBC_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include
ODBC_LFLAGS => -L/usr/lib
ODBC_LIBS => -lodbc

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent => On => On
odbc.check_persistent => On => On
odbc.default_cursortype => Static cursor => Static cursor
odbc.default_db => no value => no value
odbc.default_pw => no value => no value
odbc.default_user => no value => no value
odbc.defaultbinmode => return as is => return as is
odbc.defaultlrl => return up to 4096 bytes => return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.31 2012-07-06

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, odbc

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => 5.5.41

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

PDO_ODBC

PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) => enabled
ODBC Connection Pooling => Enabled, strict matching

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.2
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Id: a5488937a80433d434af6753d3db8517feaf91df $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => enabled
OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

Revision => $Id: 1dfa9997ed76804e53c91e0ce862f3707617b6ed $

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \> 

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: 31d836a7ac92a37b5c580836d91ad4736fe2f376 $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user 
Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary wddx 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.entropy_file => /dev/urandom => /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length => 32 => 32
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 0 => 0
session.hash_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.hash_function => 0 => 0
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => /var/lib/php5 => /var/lib/php5
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_strict_mode => Off => Off
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

shmop

shmop support => enabled

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: 363ea1fc44b0b7775e2ec3ce8456530fec6d1660 $
Schema support => enabled

soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 120 => 120
from => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

sysvmsg

sysvmsg support => enabled
Revision => $Id: adf1d2d6be849c46eed3c3ee6f1cbebd1448d6e5 $

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

wddx

WDDX Support => enabled
WDDX Session Serializer => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.1

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching => Disabled
Optimization => Disabled
Startup Failed => Opcode Caching is disabled for CLI

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename => no value => no value
opcache.consistency_checks => 0 => 0
opcache.dups_fix => Off => Off
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off
opcache.enable_file_override => Off => Off
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
opcache.fast_shutdown => 0 => 0
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.force_restart_timeout => 180 => 180
opcache.inherited_hack => On => On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 4 => 4
opcache.load_comments => 1 => 1
opcache.log_verbosity_level => 1 => 1
opcache.max_accelerated_files => 2000 => 2000
opcache.max_file_size => 0 => 0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage => 5 => 5
opcache.memory_consumption => 64 => 64
opcache.optimization_level => 0xFFFFFFFF => 0xFFFFFFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model => no value => no value
opcache.protect_memory => 0 => 0
opcache.restrict_api => no value => no value
opcache.revalidate_freq => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.save_comments => 1 => 1
opcache.use_cwd => On => On
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On

zip

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id: 05dd1ecc211075107543b0ef8cee488dd229fccf $
Zip version => 1.11.0
Libzip version => 0.10.1

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.8
Linked Version => 1.2.8

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm

Environment

Variable => Value
XDG_SESSION_ID => 1
TERM => xterm
SHELL => /bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT => 86.124.60.12 62962 22
OLDPWD => /etc/apache2
SSH_TTY => /dev/pts/1
USER => toss
LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
MAIL => /var/mail/toss
PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PWD => /var/www/xmlmanager
LANG => en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL => 1
HOME => /home/toss
LOGNAME => toss
SSH_CONNECTION => 86.124.60.12 62962 192.168.14.250 22
LESSOPEN => | /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR => /run/user/1000
LESSCLOSE => /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_ => /usr/bin/php

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
_SERVER["XDG_SESSION_ID"] => 1
_SERVER["TERM"] => xterm
_SERVER["SHELL"] => /bin/bash
_SERVER["SSH_CLIENT"] => 86.124.60.12 62962 22
_SERVER["OLDPWD"] => /etc/apache2
_SERVER["SSH_TTY"] => /dev/pts/1
_SERVER["USER"] => toss
_SERVER["LS_COLORS"] => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
_SERVER["MAIL"] => /var/mail/toss
_SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
_SERVER["PWD"] => /var/www/xmlmanager
_SERVER["LANG"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["SHLVL"] => 1
_SERVER["HOME"] => /home/toss
_SERVER["LOGNAME"] => toss
_SERVER["SSH_CONNECTION"] => 86.124.60.12 62962 192.168.14.250 22
_SERVER["LESSOPEN"] => | /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
_SERVER["XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"] => /run/user/1000
_SERVER["LESSCLOSE"] => /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_SERVER["_"] => /usr/bin/php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] => 
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] => 
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] => 
_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] => 
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => 
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] => 1422539326.0748
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1422539326
_SERVER["argv"] => Array
(
)

_SERVER["argc"] => 0

PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

I really do not understand what is happening.

---

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$content = $doc->createElement("content");
$doc->appendChild($content);

$dataADDRowTop = $doc->createElement("RowInSQL");
$content->appendChild($dataADDRowTop);

...

return $doc->saveXML();
```

---

Please do not add in comments anymore because I cannot see them for some reason (there is a comment that I get alert on phone but I cannot see it)

---

My big problem is why the value is 262144

---

Problem SOLVED. I've reinstall PHP and right now everything is working ok.

Comment: Try a `php -i | grep memory_limit` - I wonder if you are looking at the wrong `php.ini`?

Comment: The `php.ini` that you have returned is the PHP-CLI version (command line interface.) Increase the limit or optimize your code. Since you posted one line of your whole script, there's no way to figure out if you're using a library that offers caching (for example, DomPDF)

Comment: @sjagr: shouldn't the error reflect the total amount allocated?

Comment: @sjagr: What webserver environment?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Heh, I missed the command call. Probably because it wasn't formatted right in the question.

Comment: Right now when I do php -i | grep memory_limit then I get memory_limit => -1 => -1

Comment: @sjagr: Even if hadn't been stated, you'd have made a baseless assumption!

Comment: @andy1786: There you go then. You've edited the wrong php.ini file.

Comment: I am running directly under apache2 by sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: @andy1786: How are you "running directly under apache2" if you've invoked PHP from the commandline? (Hint: you're not)

Comment: Before putting this I've change I was testing with multiple memory_limit values and the default value was -1 and I've let this value

Comment: I've install apache and then php5 via sudo apt-get install php5

Comment: I've add a piece of code for better understanding

Comment: Try add command `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` into begin of your script. And then try run it in CLI mode like `php script.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I add answer because you can't see comments:

Try add command `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` into begin of your script. And then try run it in CLI mode like `php script.php`.

**EDIT 1**

how i understand that common problem - is a lot of MySQL rows. So, instead DOMDocument you can try generate XML like string like this:

```
<?php

$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$content .= '<content>';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $content .= '<tag>'.$row.'</tag>';
}
$content .= '<content>';
return $content;
```

it will be fast and use minimum memory

**EDIT 2**

Exist way that you can help you determine where is memory leak point:

1. you must limit XML rows,
2. when your script will work **without** memory errors try run xhprof (https://github.com/phacility/xhprof) to understand where is memory leak point

Comment: I am getting the same error message. It seems that the memory in the message do not change

Comment: This is an option to do the xml but this is not solving the actual problem with the memory. If I was getting that I am out of memory and the memory value was ok then this will be a valid answer but the ideea is to figure it out with the error. I will take this approach as a last one.

Comment: @andy1786 I think the reason leak of memory that `DomDocument` create object for each node. So, if you have a lot of nodes it require a lot of memory. That way DomDocument not always good solution. (i found old article about it - http://nnarhinen.tumblr.com/post/2759556700/creating-and-serving-large-xml-files-domdocument)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will check it as soon as possible. Do you have any clue why php is pushing that err on memory? The message is not real in my opinion when I look to the php.ini file. I stll think that there is the big problem

Comment: there are around 300 rows that should be in the xml. If I limit the amount on 50 then is not giving the error.

Comment: Try https://github.com/phacility/xhprof as i recommended. It will show you where is memory leak

Comment: I've tested now the approach from @stepozer and I have the same issue. I can add more rows in the xml but still is bumping on the `Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24511 bytes)` error (now is a different allocated value)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on Wheezy with php 5.4.36-0+deb7u1 while trying to run some mediawiki maintenance scripts.

It looks like the default memory_limit parameter in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini has wrong syntax and is missing the 'M' after the number. It might as well be caused by clumsy-me but I don't remember tampering with these config files since the fresh install...

I filled a bug for maintainers just in case (#793385).